# Windows 10 having trouble detecting devices on the network using file explorer

Tags: windows, networking, workgroup, sharing

I've been trying to set up my new laptop for network sharing, but it does not show up under the network tab in file explorer (it is a brand new MSI gaming laptop). The laptop can see all devices and access files on other computers perfectly fine but cannot be accessed from any other device. All options under file and printer sharing have been enabled on all devices and I still cant get it to work.

I've also tried to add a file from the laptop to share to the network and still no luck. I've also been browsing similar threads and heard about enabling 'netBios' which I have also done on all computers, restarted, and still nothing. I have also disabled the firewall on it and nothing changed.

I have also tested the connection between my desktop and my laptop using ping and it works just fine, so they are connected.

I would appreciate any help on this as its getting pretty frustrating.

Note: All devices are running Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Pro. (The laptop is on windows home)

The laptop is connected via the 5G band on wifi, my desktop is on Ethernet, maybe that is important?

Comment: Is your WiFi set to [Isolation mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/179089/lock-down-your-wi-fi-network-with-your-routers-wireless-isolation-option/)? Have you checked your firewall settings?

Comment: No it is not, I have checked my firewall for obvious problems but perhaps I looked over something, what specifically should I be looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot see computers on network](https://superuser.com/questions/1314989/cannot-see-computers-on-network)

Comment: That being said, I encountered the same scenario with one of the computers on my home network after the upgrade to version 1809, and the troubleshooting steps within the accepted answer (referenced above) solved the problem.

Comment: Have done everything on the list and problem still persists, one of the computers actually does not detect itself anymore.

Comment: You did *everything* within the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1315925/650163), but that problem still persists?  That is rather difficult to imagine, and it makes me think that there might be some type of third-party software or configuration on that laptop that is preventing the standard fixes from working.  Nonetheless, while we are always glad to help this really **is** a duplicate of the referenced question, and should be flagged that way.